# Why can't I get the local User's IP address when they visit my Web page?

Tags: c#, ip, asp.net-core-6.0

I am trying to get the visiting user's IP address from my Web site.  I was able to get my own IIS Server IP address(es); however, that is not what I need. I am looking for the User's IP address.  Specifically, I am looking for the IP address that is generated by a https://whatismyipaddress.com/ access.

I have managed to get my own ISP IIS Server IP with this code on my View.cshtml:

```
@using System
@using System.Text 
@using System.Net
@using System.Net.Sockets
@{
    string myIP = string.Empty;   
    IPHostEntry heserver = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
    foreach (IPAddress curAdd in heserver.AddressList)
    {
        if (curAdd.AddressFamily.ToString() == ProtocolFamily.InterNetwork.ToString())
            myIP += curAdd + " ";
    }
}
```

In the case above, myIP depicts my own IIS IP addresses.  How do I query for the Visiting user's IP address on my .NET 6.0 Web application?

Comment: `server = Dns.GetHostName();`  That's the local host.

Comment: The Request has a UserHostAddress property with the clients address. But be aware there is no guarantee that this is the IP of the "real" client. Anything in between beginning from some NAT behavior to Gateways will change that. And that behavior is not attached to this Property. Its in the nature of TCP/IP networking.

Comment: @Ralf,  I agree completely.  I am currently looking at another option, such as using one of the Web-Based API services that provides a JSON result set of the client visitor data.

Comment: Agree with @Ralf, I don't think you can get the local user's IP as you expected. There is a high probability that the network operator or other IP addresses may be obtained. I have tried `IHttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress` and it can't get the  local request user's IP.